# Google Translate with fixed top navbar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, google-translate, navbar

I use Twitter Bootsrap's navbar to put a navigation bar on top of my website. (class="navbar navbar-fixed-top")
I also need to use Google Translate widget.
I use tools written [here](http://translate.google.com/translate_tools).

But when user selects a language to translate, Google puts a horizontal navbar on top of my page.
That bar masks my own navbar.
I need my navbar appear just below the Google's horizontal bar.

Should I use z-index ? But in that case one of them will mask other navbar?
Is there a better solution? To show one of them below another?
Thank you

edit: when I add following code to the top of my page, Google puts a navbar before my navbar, and everything seems well. But the bad thing is, Google's navbar is visible for every user. I need to show only to the users that doesn't speak my page's language.

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div><script>
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({
    pageLanguage: 'fr',
    layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL
  }, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

edit: I suppose there is no option like "show google translate if language is different" and "show horizontal bar. If i load horizontal bar without considering the user's language everything is working fine. But the native speakers see the Google Translate bar. Which takes space from my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easy option would be

```
<div class="navbar-inner" style="padding-top:39px;">
```

Comment: Google's bar is not always visible. It is shown if user's language is different than my page's language. If I put this into my page, my navbar will always be 39px lower than the top of page. When Google translate is not shown, that 39px will be empty. Is it possible to add padding to navbar if Google's bar is visible? By using jquery or html/div. Thank you

Comment: possible but since the change of the .goog-te-combo select trigger an event on element.js you may have to work on a downloaded copy of element.js. You may be better off working from the API if you want to customise : https://developers.google.com/translate/

Answer (score 9):

This would be a ugly solution but a quick one.

After clicked the  tag will automatically add class="translated-ltr" or "translated-rtl". Use these class to hack your fixed header.

```
html.translated-ltr .navbar-inner, html.translated-ltr .navbar-inner { padding-top: 39px; }
```

Comment: I don't prefer a CSS solution, I look for a js solution. But if I put this code into my js file as a Jquery line, I suppose putting it into "document.load" is not enough..

Comment: It was though exactly what I needed. Didn't spot the change to the HTML class due to all the MOdernizr stuff. But this made my life sooo much easier. Nice one Peter.

Comment: I think the correct answer should be `html.translated-ltr body nav.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top { padding-top: 39px; }`

Answer (score 3):

i use jQuery to check it, im using this code :

```
setInterval(function(){ 
if ( $('html').hasClass('translated-ltr')) {
  $('.navbar').css('margin-top','30px');
}else{
  $('.navbar').css('margin-top','0px');
}
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Very good solution, works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to share my experience, I have used [Arthron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50084035/5327495) and it works.

**But have a little bug** if click the `translate` / `show the original` on the translate bar, the logic return false when the actual is true (translated bar visible). So I add this and perfect :

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("skiptranslate")[1].style.visibility=='visible'
&& document.getElementsByClassName("skiptranslate")[0].style.display!='none'
```

full code :

```js
setInterval(function(){
    if ( $('html').hasClass('translated-ltr') ||
    (document.getElementsByClassName("skiptranslate")[1].style.visibility=='visible' &&
document.getElementsByClassName("skiptranslate")[0].style.display!='none')) {
      $('.navbar').css('margin-top','30px');
    }else{
      $('.navbar').css('margin-top','0px');
    }
}, 500);
```